# Generics in static methods in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to set up a mixin with standard persistence behavior. The mixin looks like that:

```
mixin Persistence<T> {
  static late final PersistenceBase persistence;

  static void add(T object) {
    persistence.add(object);
  }

  static void delete(T object) {
    persistence.delete(object);
  }

  static T elementAt(int index) => persistence.elementAt(index);

  static Iterable<T> getAll() => persistence.getAll();

  static T get first => persistence.getFirst();
  static T get last => persistence.getLast();
  static int get length => persistence.getLength();
}
```

Usage of persistence would look like that:

```
class A with Persistence {
  String var1;
  int var2;
}

A.add(A("test", 1));
var length = A.getLength();
A firstElement = A.getFirst();
```

However Dart doesn't allow using generics with static methods:

> Static members can't reference type parameters of the class.
> Try removing the reference to the type parameter, or making the member an instance member

The point is that I don't want to create instance of `A` class just to access persistence functionality for the class.

So far I have done this way:

```
class PersistenceManager<T> {
  late final PersistenceBase persistence;

  void add(T object) {
    persistence.add(object);
  }

  void delete(T object) {
    persistence.delete(object);
  }

  T elementAt(int index) => persistence.elementAt(index);

  Iterable<T> getAll() => persistence.getAll();

  T get first => persistence.getFirst();
  T get last => persistence.getLast();
  int get length => persistence.getLength();
}

class Asset {
  static final persistenceMgr = PersistenceManager<Asset>();
  ...
}

Asset.persistenceMgr.add(Asset());
```

That though requires adding mandatory static field for each class that would use persistence.

Is there other more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work.

Dart mixin application works by mixing in the *instance* members of the mixin, and doing nothing to the static members.

You won't be able to do `A.elementAt(...)` with or without generics, because the `A` class doesn't have any static `elementAt` method. The `Persistance` mixin has one, but you have to call it as `Persistance.elementAt`. It's not the same namespace as `A`, and there is no inheritance, or mixin-in, of static members.

If you want a `PersistanceBase` *per class*, you do need to declare it yourself, and putting the methods which operate on the base onto the same per-class value seems like the optimal design.

So, no, there is no other more elegant solution. What you have *is* elegant.